# Javascript: disable element on countdown to date

Tags: javascript

I have a button which I disable depending on whether an datetime has passed, however, this will only work on page load, how can I set a countdown timer so that my button is disabled when the countdown to the `nominationCloseDateTime` is reached even if the page is already loaded.

`<ctx><vars><nominationCloseDateTime>2022-05-10 04:56:00.000Z</nominationCloseDateTime></vars></ctx>`

```
var nominationCloseDateTime = document.controller.getValue('/ctx/vars/nominationCloseDateTime');

if (nominationCloseDateTime < $.now()) {
    $('input#nominate').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

I've calculated the countdown to date in seconds, now whats next?

```
 var nominationCloseDateTimeCountDownSecs = ((new Date(document.controller.getValue('/ctx/vars/nominationCloseDateTime')).getTime()) - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
```

Is the following correct?

```
setTimeout(() => {
  $('input#nominate').prop('disabled', true);
}, nominationCloseDateTimeCountDownSecs)
```

Comment: Consider performing the check at regular intervals (say every 10 minutes or every 1 second or every 1 hour, based on your requirement). So, try something using `setInterval`, may be ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function.

For example,

```js
//calculate, in seconds, how much time you want the button to stay enabled.
const calculatedTimeUntilCloseDateTime;

setTimeout(() => {
  functionToDisableYourButton();
}, calculatedTimeUntilCloseDateTime)
```

It will work like below:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
}, 1000)
```